# Add git-ftp-include to wordpress project

Tags: wordpress, bitbucket-pipelines

I use git-ftp and bitbucket pipelines for my Wordpress project CI/CD. I make the wp-content git repo. I use Webpack to bundle the files and I also add dist folder to gitignore. Here is my setup:

wp-content/bitbucket-pipelines:

```
image: node:12.13.1

pipelines:
 branches:
   develop:
     - step:
         name: Deploy to staging
         deployment: staging
         script:
           - cd themes/my-theme
           - npm install
           - npm run build
           - apt-get update
           - apt-get -qq install git-ftp
           - git ftp push --syncroot themes/my-theme/  --user $FTP_username --passwd $FTP_password $HOST/wp-content/themes/my-theme/
```

The pipeline works just fine. However, it does not upload the dist folder to the host. I think that's because I add dist to my gitignore. How can I add the .git-ftp-include. Should I create the file and upload it to the host (under my-theme) or should I add it to my local and upload it to bitbucket

.git-ftp-include

```
themes/my-theme/dist/
```

.gitignore (under wp-content)

```
# ignore specific themes
themes/twenty*/

themes/my-theme/css/style.css

uploads
plugins
languages
cache
ai1wm-backups
dist
node_modules/
.idea/
.DS_Store
.log
```

Comment: Can you please post your .gitignore file here

Comment: Ok, I have just added it

Comment: Try this `!.git-ftp-include` in `.gitignore` file

Comment: I can see that file is uploaded to my bitbucket. Since the syncroot points to my theme folder while my git points to wp-content, should I add the git-ftp-include under my-theme or wp-content?

Comment: What is the server os, if it is Linux/Ubuntu please check by `ls -la`, it will list all the files including the hidden file.

Comment: I add the git-ftp-include to my-theme and I can see it's there